# FirebaseInitProvider Error When a library added

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to run the app on my device, everything goes well till adding emojilike library(commented out below in the code).  App works on emulator, the problem only occurs on my phone.

I also try adding some other library from github, it worked too. I know there are similar issues on stackoverflow but I try all of them.

I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.koddev-SBJ0Pe4ZQGhO6xUQ4jTjYg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.koddev-SBJ0Pe4ZQGhO6xUQ4jTjYg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.koddev"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'

    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.github.andob:emojilike-android:beta3'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-ios:0.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```